# How to update values dynamically for the individual match sections within sshd config file using puppet

Tags: list, arraylist, indexing, puppet

i am able to update the value to the sections "User foo" and "Host *.example.net" by passing the index. If i pass index 1 or 2 the respective value is getting updated.

my code:

```
$sections = ['Host *.example.net', 'User foo']

$sections.each |String $section| {
  sshd_config_match { "${section}":
    ensure => present,
  }
}

$settings = [['User foo', 'X11Forwarding yes', 'banner none'],['Host *.example.net', 'X11Forwarding no', 'banner none']]
$settings.each |Array $setting| {
  $setting_array = split($setting[1],/ /)
  sshd_config { "${setting_array[0]} ${setting[0]}":
    ensure    => present,
    key       => "${setting_array[0]}",
    condition => "${setting[0]}",
    value     => "${setting_array[1]}",
  }
}
```

current result:

```
 Match Host *.example.net
      # Created by Puppet
      X11Forwarding no
     
    Match User foo
      # Created by Puppet
      X11Forwarding yes
```

Expected results:

```
Match Host *.example.net
  # Created by Puppet
  X11Forwarding no
  Banner none
Match User foo
  # Created by Puppet
  X11Forwarding yes
  Banner none
```

i am able to update only one value mentioned in the index but am looking a way to update more or all the values mentioned in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what module is providing your `sshd_config_match` and `sshd_config` resource types, nor, therefore, exactly what they do.  Nevertheless, if we consider this code ...

> ```
> $settings = [['User foo', 'X11Forwarding yes', 'banner none'],['Host *.example.net', 'X11Forwarding no', 'banner none']]
> $settings.each |Array $setting| {
>   $setting_array = split($setting[1],/ /)
>   sshd_config { "${setting_array[0]} ${setting[0]}":
>     ensure    => present,
>     key       => "${setting_array[0]}",
>     condition => "${setting[0]}",
>     value     => "${setting_array[1]}",
>   }
> }
> ```

... we can see that each element of `$settings` is a three-element array, of which the `each` call accesses only those at indexes 0 and 1.  That seems to match up with the result you see, which does not contain anything corresponding to the data from the elements at index 2.

You *could* iterate over the inner `$setting` elements, starting at index 1, instead of considering that element only, but I would suggest instead restructuring the data more naturally, and writing code suited to the restructured data.  You have data of mixed significance in your arrays, and you are needlessly jamming keys and values together such that you need to spend effort to break them back apart.  Structuring the data as a hash of hashes instead of an array of arrays could be a good start:

```
$settings = {
  'User foo'           => { 'X11Forwarding' => 'yes', 'banner' => 'none'},
  'Host *.example.net' => { 'X11Forwarding' => 'no',  'banner' => 'none'},
}
```

Not only does that give you much enhanced *readability* (mostly from formatting), but it also affords much greater *usability*.  To wit, although I'm guessing a bit here, you should be able to do something similar to the following:

```
$settings.each |String $condition, Hash $properties| {
  $properties.each |String $key, String $value| {
    sshd_config { "${condition} ${key}":
      ensure    => 'present',
      condition => $condition,
      key       => $key,
      value     => $value,
    }
  }
}
```

Again, greater readability, this time largely from a helpful choice of names, and along with it greater clarity that something like this is in fact the right structure for the code (supposing that I have correctly inferred enough about the types you are using).

Comment: your code is working and am able to get the expected result but my input will always be in the list format as i have mentioned above in the question. Is it possible to change the code according to the list format? kindly help.

Comment: @Docgyan, as this answer already observes, "You could iterate over the inner `$setting` elements, starting at index 1, instead of considering that element only".  The would take the general form of putting a `$setting[1,-1].each |...| { ... }` around the inner resource declaration.  But again, I urge you to structure the data better.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I would need your extended help regarding the same issue. Currently what am looking for is, If sections is not matching then i just need to update 'X11Forwarding' => 'yes' (key => value) and if section is matching then i need to update the value inside match section. Hoping for the reply.

Comment: That would be a separate question, @Docgyan.  Moreover, although this answer turned out to be possible without me knowing the details of the resource types you are using, it seems unlikely that the same would be true for your followup.

Comment: as mentioned i have posted a new question considering your above comments, kindly help. link for the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63271537/how-to-update-values-for-match-and-general-section-in-sshd-config-using-puppet

Comment: it would be a great help if you could explain your code, As am new to coding and puppet i want to know how the entries getting updated under ("User foo" or Host *.example.com")

Comment: @Docgyan, to the extent that the details of how the target system's configuration get updated based on the above code, that's a function of Puppet itself and the resource types you are using.  It is an intentional part of Puppet's design that the person writing manifest code such as the above doesn't have to know or care about that.