# How to update values for Match and general section in sshd config using puppet

Tags: list, dictionary, puppet, sshd

Below is the code:

```
$sections = ['Host *.example.net', 'User foo']

$sections.each |String $section| {
  sshd_config_match { "${section}":
    ensure => present,
  }
}
$settings = {
  'User foo'           => { 'X11Forwarding' => 'yes', 'banner' => 'none'},
  'Host *.example.net' => { 'X11Forwarding' => 'no',  'banner' => 'none'},
}
$settings.each |String $condition, Hash $properties| {
  $properties.each |String $key, String $value| {
    sshd_config { "${condition} ${key}":
      ensure    => 'present',
      condition => $condition,
      key       => $key,
      value     => $value,
    }
  }
}
```

Currently the key and value( ex:'X11Forwarding' => 'yes')  is getting updated under the Match section as mentioned below in the screenshot:

[image]

I am looking for the key value( ex:'X11Forwarding' => 'yes') to be updated in global section if at all the section is not matched as mentioned in the below scrrenshot:

[image]

Currently above code works good for Match section and looking to update the gobal section if the section is not matched.

I am new to coding and also apologies if my question is confusing, Kindly help.

Comment: As I remarked in conjunction with [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251501), we need to know what module is providing your `sshd_config` and `sshd_config_match` resource types if we are to advise you on this matter.  And if it is proprietary and closed then we probably cannot help -- in that case, you would be best off seeking help from the maintainer.

Comment: @John https://forge.puppet.com/herculesteam/augeasproviders_ssh/2.4.0/types provides sshd_config and sshd_config_match resource types.

Comment: Ok, we can work with that.  Now, when you say you want to update the top-level properties "if at all the section is not matched", what exactly do you mean?  Matched by what?  Do you perhaps mean that where a key of the `$settings` hash does not appear in the `$sections` array, you want the corresponding configuration settings to appear at the global level of the target config file?